# Google Maps API's initialize function without ONLOAD body tag or before end body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a website that uses the DotNetNuke CMS. I've added a Google Maps map using the API, but I need to call the initialize() function when the page has loaded. Usually you'd do this with:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
```

or add the following just before the < /body> tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        initialize();
    }
</script>
```

I however do not have access to the body tag, or exact end of the  tag. Is there any other way to call this function without doing the aforementioned?

Comment: Couldn't you put that script section anywhere in the code. As long as it is towards the bottom of whatever you can edit?

Comment: @ Rafe, I've tried, but unfortunately not possible for a specific page. It'd result into the code appearing on every single page on the website (30.000 pages instead of 1). A little too much in my opinion. I've figured out the solution though, check the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a good idea to do this on a window load event - if you've got some high-latency images or other assets loading then your google map will load very slowly. Just before the closing body tag, add this:

```
<script>
 initialize();
</script>
```

All that google needs to be ready before it builds it's map is the DOM, not every single asset on the page. The DOM is always fully loaded by the time the script loads right before the closing body tag.

**EDIT**

Technically, all that google maps needs to be ready before it builds it's map is the div that it is going to be placed in. So you don't even need to have the script before your closing body tag, you could have it immediately after your map div tag like this:

```
<html>
...
<body>
...html...

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script>initialize();</script>


...more html
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

I've figured out when I was just randomly trying something. Matter of adding the following to the headers. Long live API V3!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Don't attach this to a window load event, see my answer below for the reason why you shouldn't use this event.

Answer (score 1):

You can call following way as well

```
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>

    $("#map-canvas").on("load", function () {
       initialize();            
    });
```